# Extend biholomorphic map on punctured disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\dot{D}$ the punctured version of $D$. Suppose I have a biholomorphic map $f: \dot{D} \to \dot{D}$. How can I use the Riemann extension theorem to show I have an extension of $f$ from $D$ onto itself which is again biholomorphic?

Since $f$ is bounded I know there is a holomorphic extension $\hat{f}: \dot{D} \to \mathbb{C}$. By continuity we must have $\hat{f}(D) \subset D$, but how to show that $\hat{f}(0) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(0)=w\ne0$. Then there exists $a\in \dot D$ such that $f(a)=f(0)=w$. Let $0<r<|a|/2$. Then $B_r(0)\cap B_r(a)=\emptyset$. By the Open mapping theoren $f$ is open. Then $f(B_r(0))\cap f(B_r(a))$ is an open set containig $w$. This implies that $f$ is not injective in $\dot D$, which is a contradiction.